# Internet Explorer 7 Javascript Problem?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

This script works in IE8 and Firefox, but it doesn't apply the "current" class or clear the "style" in IE7. Anyone know why? I replaced the real ID's and file paths with generic ones when I copied it here for security purposes.

```
var img = document.getElementById("imageID");
var div = document.getElementById("divID");

if (img.getAttribute('src') == "imagefilepath.gif") {
div.className = "current";
div.setAttribute('style', ' ' );
}
```

Comment: What does `img.getAttribute('src')` contain if not `"imagefilepath.gif"`?

Comment: It could contain a number of different file paths. I have a long IF block, but I just copied the top IF statement here.

Comment: IE 7 (and earlier) doesn't support 'class' and 'style' for `setAttribute`.

Comment: Oh Really? Hmm, okay, I guess I'll try and find another way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that IE7 includes the entire path in the `src` attribute, your condition isn't being met.

http://jsfiddle.net/4E58r/1/

Comment: Well I do use the whole path in the real script. "imagefilepath.gif" was just a generic path I replaced it with because I didn't want to put the real file path on here.

Comment: No, you were right! Thanks. I did a I wrapped the IF in a contains block and that fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this that'll work in all versions:

```
someId.setAttribute("className", "someClassName") || 
someId.setAttribute("class", "someClassName")
```